# issue while WSO2 EI reading JWT response

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I used wso2 EI7.0.0 micro-integrator I try to call end point that sends to me JWT message but I got this error when read JWT response

```
Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:452)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:215)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:239)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:809)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:309)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'e' (code 101) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]
```

I used after call mediator `<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>`

but still I faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the endpoint is probably failing and sending an HTML response with an error rather than sending you the JWT with a content type like `application/json`. Having said that, by default there aren't any message builders to handle HTML contents, so try adding the following to the `deployment.toml`. This will let you handle the HTML content you are receiving.

```ini
[[custom_message_builders]]
class = "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"
content_type = "text/html"
```

Comment: The custom message builders text/html is already exist in deployment.toml, the issues in my sequence that the content-type of body response from external end point is (application/jwt) the body is JWT content. this body response is not built or formatted it's started with eyJ1c2VyX2luZm. I think WSO2 can't handle or read a JWT response format , so how can I solve it?    Thank you,

Comment: @Sarah please add a sample response payload you are getting. Edit the original question and add it there.